# Programmatically Add a new Dojo AccordionPane to Existing AccordionContainer

Tags: dojo, accordion

I am trying to add a new AccordionPane to a existing container, but for the life of me I can't get it to work.

Is anyone able to suggest where I am going wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">  </script>  

        <script type="text/javascript">  
            dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane"); 
            dojo.require("dijit.layout.AccordionContainer");
        </script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4.0/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function AddNewPane() {
                var accordPane = new dijit.layout.AccordionPane({"title": "test", "content":"hello"});
                dijit.layout.AccordionContainer("myacc").addChild(accordPane);
                accordPane.startup();
                //select the new Pane
                accordPane.selected = true;
            }      
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="AddNewPane();" >Add</button>

        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" id="myacc" class="tundra" >
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" title="Origional Acc 1" >
                Testing One
            </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" title="Origional Acc 2" >
                Testing Two
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            document.getElementById("myacc").style.width = '200px';
            document.getElementById("myacc").style.height = '200px';
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it working, thanks.

```
        function Testing() {
            var accordion = dijit.byId("myacc"); 
            var d = new dijit.layout.AccordionPane({id:'newpane', title:'hello', content: 'testing'}); 
            accordion.addChild(d, 0); 
            dijit.byId('myacc').selectChild(dijit.byId('newpane'));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

As the [original poster said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3563063/942841), to add the new AccordionPane to the **TOP** of the AccordionContainer, use 0 for the *insertIndex*.
If you'd rather add the new AccordionPanel to the **BOTTOM** of the AccordionContainer, just remove the *insertIndex* from the .addChild as seen below:

```
        function Testing() {
            var accordion = dijit.byId("myacc"); 
            var d = new dijit.layout.AccordionPane({id:'newpane', title:'hello', content: 'testing'}); 
            accordion.addChild(d); 
            accordion.selectChild(dijit.byId('newpane'));
        }
```

Also, in my case I was wanting to add a new AccordionPane to the AccordionContainer with content loaded from another page on the same server. Code below for anyone who finds this in the future wanting to do the same:

```
        function Testing() {
            var accordion = dijit.byId("myacc"); 
            var d = new dijit.layout.AccordionPane({id:'newpane', title:'hello', href: "location/of/page.php", preload: true}); 
            accordion.addChild(d); 
            accordion.selectChild(dijit.byId('newpane'));
        }
```

Also, if you want to enable animation when selecting the child, add *true* to the *animate* property:

```
            accordion.selectChild(dijit.byId('newpane'), true);
```